# simulated turtlebot kinect data

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to get simulated raw image or create Point Cloud in Rviz with simulated Kinect and simulated Turtlebot "out of the box"? Because I can only get laser data posted on /scan topic. I tried to build Point Cloud but there is no published topic to do that. Is that even possible in simulated environment or do I have to reroute some of the data to other topic.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Electric.

I would really appreciate any tips because I'm new to ROS :)

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28595/simulated-turtlebot-kinect-data/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the gazebo.urdf.xacro file. The camera frame names were not correct and therefore the gazebo plugins couldn't initialize properly. It's fixed in 330:4253a4e5f257 . I'll push out a release today with the fix, turtlebot 0.9.2

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-28**:
It worked fine for me before i updated my packages recently. I started using real turtle n hence couldn't notice this issue. Anyways thanks for the update :)

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-02-29**:
I've done this as well previously, although I may have done an update since then. In that test I added a table to the world and viewed the pointcloud in rviz.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-29**:
Ya i have performed mapping n ran navigation stack also in a office environment that i created.